# To get the total number of pages in an RTF document present in an IFS As400 folder in java

Tags: java, rtf, jt400

I have a requirement to get the total number of pages in an RTF document which resides in an IFS folder within AS400 system.
I am able to get the page details for PDF documents using iTextPDF PDFReader but i have run into a road block for RTF documents.
Or is there a way to read the footer of this RTF document, because i have the total number of pages defined in the footer.I am able to read the document line by line but not the footer content.

Please provide me some help on this.I am stuck on this for days..

Im using the below code to fetch the details for PDF.

```
AS400 as400 = new AS400("xxx.com","abc","xxxx");
 String filePath = "/QDLS/FOLDERLIST/FOLDER1/FOLDER2/";

IFSFile qdlsDirectory = new IFSFile(as400,filePath);

IFSFile[] files = qdlsDirectory.listFiles();

for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++){
    fileName = files[i].getName();
                                    if(fileName.toLowerCase().indexOf(".pdf") != -1 && fileName.toLowerCase().indexOf(mixCodes.toLowerCase())!=-1) {  
PdfReader document = new PdfReader(new IFSFileInputStream(files[i])); 
pageCount = document.getNumberOfPages();  
}
```

Comment: I removed references to PDF and iText because the RTF package has been removed from iText since 2009. As for your question: PDF is rendered at the moment of creation, so the number of pages is known and fixed. RTF is rendered in the viewer, at the moment a person reads it. The same document can have a different number of pages depending on the application used to view the file. In other words: your assignment doesn't always make sense.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie..thanks.As Chris suggested , i had tried to use RTFEditorKit but to no avail...The document is generated by an AS400 job & it contains tables with data.

Comment: You could use a RTF to PDF converter and then read the PDF page count.

Answer (score 0):

You can count explicit page breaks with a slight modification of the code in [RTF Line count in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138318/rtf-line-count-in-java) (which provides an example of reading an RTF document and calculating a line count). You could use similar code to count explicit page breaks, just modifying the last line to read:

```
System.out.println(plainText.split("\\page").length);
```

Comment: @Chris...i tried the above option.I am getting an exception "Invalid RTF content! Invalid insert" followed by java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown character property name {a} near index 2. \page   ^.....The RTF document in concern has tables within ..So would that cause an issue?

Comment: I don't know - have you tried running it on a simpler document to test the theory?

Comment: @Chris.Nope.i will try it out on a simpler doc.

Comment: @Chris..I created a simple Rtf doc & inserted 3 pages but the above command plainText.split seems to throw error since \page is not present in the plaintext representation of the doc.

Comment: If \page is not there, then there are no _explicit_ page breaks in the document.  Refer to Bruno's comment on the question; RTF can have variable number of pages based on the viewer, the only page breaks that are 'for sure' there are the explicit ones.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie .. I was able to implement the same above logic using scanner class.Scanner class was able to identify the page break but some how the RTF APis were not able to ..since it was breaking because of the embedded tables ..'while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        if (line != null) {
         if (line.contains("\\page")) {
          count++;
}
}
}'..but the problem is .this process is time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Approximate:

- Count all \par and \line tokens in the document.
- Use a regex to strip all RTF tokens from the document.
- Use the remaining document size and an average number of characters per page to calculate an estimated page count.

Answer (score 0):

According to the RTF standard, an optional information group may include the page count in the \nofpagesN entry, where N is the page count.
Note that this value may be inaccurate. It is set by the RTF writer application.

Reference:

https://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading25